# Missing text/blank space on Ubuntu web sites using Google Chrome

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, fedora, kde

When visiting ubuntu.com or askubuntu.com, Google Chrome displays blank spaces instead of most of the expected text of the web site. The sites look like this:

[image]

I am using Google Chrome 20.0.1132.47 beta on Fedora 17 x86_64 under KDE.

So far I have tried:

- Removed `~/.cache/google-chrome` and restarted Chrome - No change.
- Removed `~/.config/google-chrome` and restarted Chrome - No change.
- Removed both of the above and restarted Chrome - No change.
- Logged in as a different user - Works.

when I login as a different user, Chrome displays the sites properly. In addition, when I remove the `~/.config/google-chrome` and `~/.cache/google-chrome` directories and restart Chrome to generate a new configuration, the problem persists. These lead me to believe that the trouble has something to do with my user account, though exactly what is unclear.

Where else should I look for the source of this problem?

Comment: After being updated to 21.0.1180.41 the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an apparently corrupt copy of the [Ubuntu fonts](http://font.ubuntu.com/) in my `~/.fonts` directory. After removing them, I can view all of these sites normally again.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue on Ubuntu 22.04.

Disabling hardware acceleration from chrome settings https://chrome://settings/system solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to verify your font settings in your chrome profile (Settings > Advanced > Web Content). I had run into a similar issue in the past that was solved with a change to my font settings.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the hardware acceleration helped, but seems like a workaround rather than a solution. In case you don't know how to reach it in 2023:
Open this URL in your Chrome Browser:
*chrome://settings/?search=hardware*.

What helped me in the long run was re-generating the fonts cache.
Uhm, what?
I noticed that the "fonts" app (should be "gnome-font-viewer") was hanging when I started it as a non-sudo user. This was also mentioned here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348344/fonts-app-hangs-after-being-opened

Anyway I opened a Terminal session, switched to a sudo user (`su <username>`) and ran `sudo gnome-font-viewer`). It opened and regenerated the fonts. Afterwards I closed that window, logged out as the sudo user and reopened the "fonts" app as my non-sudo user - It wasn't hanging anyore.

Afterwards I could re-enable hardware acceleration in Chrome and the fonts were displayed as usual again.